# Algorithm to create a bitmap/canvas image from binary 1's and 0's to visually see the data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, bitmap

Let's say I have 20,164 binary digits in a standard JavaScript string, for example:

```
var data = '101010101010101010101010100110001011010101101' ...
```

What I want to do is see a visual representation of these digits by converting it to a bitmap or perhaps HTML5 canvas image. So if I loop through all the bits and it comes across a 1 it will draw a black pixel, and a 0 the pixel will be white.

So I'm guessing I'll need a 142 x 142 pixel grid something which looks like this:

[image: binary data bitmap]

What's an algorithm or way to do this in JavaScript? All I need to do is display it on the web page so maybe creating a basic bitmap or canvas or SVG image will be fine.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're exactly correct with the HTML5 canvas idea.  You could try something like the following if you don't want to do base64 data.

Javascript (with no error checking):

```
var string = "1010101...";
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";  // Fill with white first
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 142, 142);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
for (var i = 0; i < 142; i++) {  // Loop through each character
    for (var j = 0; j < 142; j++) {
        if (string[i*142+j] == '1')     // If the character is one,
            ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1 );  // fill the pixel with black
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <canvas width=142 height=142 id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

If you use this, you should make sure to check that the length of the string is the length you are expecting.

Comment: What about filling everything with white and then drawing only black pixels?

Comment: That would be a much better idea *facepalm*.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.src ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9oMCRUiMrIBQVkAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAADElEQVQI12NgoC4AAABQAAEiE+h1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
```

Comment: OK so I have to convert it to BASE64 first? Looks promising, can you put in the HTML markup as well?

Comment: a string is a string, so you can put it anywhere you can keep a string.

Answer (score 2):

You may also include the image directly in the HTML without using JS:

Example:

```
<img alt='' src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgASALMAAOfn5+rq6uvr6+zs7O7u7vHx8fPz8/b29vj4+P39/f///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwAAAAABgASAAAIMAAVCBxIsKDBgwgTDkzAsKGAhxARSJx4oKJFAxgzFtjIkYDHjwNCigxAsiSAkygDAgA7'/>
```

But the image must be in a correct format: jpg, tiff, png, etc. not just as a bitmap.
You may easily convert a bitmap to formats like BMP.